# Forgot password needs to redirect from wp-login to a custom page

Tags: wordpress

Am new in wordpress. My doubt is,

Now default user forgot password redirecting to `website/wp-login.php?action=lostpassword&redirect_to=http%3A%2F%2website.com%2Fuser-profile`

But I have a custom page `/password-reset/`. So I refer some post and added below code in my theme function.php

```
add_filter( 'lostpassword_url', 'my_lostpassword_url', 10, 0 ); 
function my_lostpassword_url() {
    return site_url('/password-reset/');
}
```

But it's not working.

So I added rewrite rule in **.htaccess** file - as first line

```
RewriteRule ^wp-login.php?action=lostpassword$ website.com/password-reset/ [R=301,L]
```

Both are not working. Any solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a good tutorial to follow : https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/build-a-custom-wordpress-user-flow-part-3-password-reset--cms-23811